# UIPanGestureRecognizer - Only vertical or horizontal

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view that has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to drag the view vertically. So in the recognizer callback, I only update the y-coordinate to move it. The superview of this view, has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that will drag the view horizontally, just updating the x-coordinate.

The problem is that the first `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is taking the event to move the view vertically, so I can not use the superview gesture.

I have tried

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
 shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
                            (UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```

and both will work, but I don't want that. I want the horizontally to be detected only if the movement is clearly horizontal. So it would be great if the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` had a direction property.

How can I achieve this behavior? I find the docs very confusing, so maybe someone can explain it better here.

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question and accept the answer, if you figured out the solution.

Comment: @JoeBlow really? So, maybe you made category of swipe gesture to receive translation and velocity of gesture?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  If you want to detect **a horizontal swipe**, this is totally and completely **built-in to the operating system**. All the work is entirely and totally done for you.  You need do ... nothing!  :)  Just paste in the two lines of code in this example ..  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20988648/294884   Note that you can choose left only" "right only" or "both".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I figured it out creating a subclass of UIPanGestureRecognizer

DirectionPanGestureRecognizer:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

typedef enum {
    DirectionPangestureRecognizerVertical,
    DirectionPanGestureRecognizerHorizontal
} DirectionPangestureRecognizerDirection;

@interface DirectionPanGestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer {
    BOOL _drag;
    int _moveX;
    int _moveY;
    DirectionPangestureRecognizerDirection _direction;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) DirectionPangestureRecognizerDirection direction;

@end
```

DirectionPanGestureRecognizer.m:

```
#import "DirectionPanGestureRecognizer.h"

int const static kDirectionPanThreshold = 5;

@implementation DirectionPanGestureRecognizer

@synthesize direction = _direction;

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) return;
    CGPoint nowPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint prevPoint = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self.view];
    _moveX += prevPoint.x - nowPoint.x;
    _moveY += prevPoint.y - nowPoint.y;
    if (!_drag) {
        if (abs(_moveX) > kDirectionPanThreshold) {
            if (_direction == DirectionPangestureRecognizerVertical) {
                self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
            }else {
                _drag = YES;
            }
        }else if (abs(_moveY) > kDirectionPanThreshold) {
            if (_direction == DirectionPanGestureRecognizerHorizontal) {
                self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
            }else {
                _drag = YES;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)reset {
    [super reset];
    _drag = NO;
    _moveX = 0;
    _moveY = 0;
}

@end
```

This will only trigger the gesture if the user starts dragging in the selected behavior. Set the direction property to a correct value and you are all set.

Comment: I think 'reset' is not getting called initially.  Added an `initWithTarget:action:` method and called reset and all was well.

Comment: In current implementation `DirectionPanGestureRecognizer` will disregard fast drags, unless you set `kDirectionPanThreshold = 20` or so, in which case it can give false alarms. I suggest putting `abs(_moveX) > abs(_moveY)` instead of `abs(_moveX) > kDirectionPanThreshold` and changing horizontal case respectively.

Comment: I should add this this was helpful for me as well, but what I had to add to get the pan gesture recognizer to trigger was in the else part of the if, under the line `_drag = YES` I added `self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;`

Answer (score 228):

Just do this for the vertical pan gesture recognizer, it works for me:

```objectivec
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:someView];
    return fabs(velocity.y) > fabs(velocity.x);
}
```

And for Swift:

```swift
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let velocity = gestureRecognizer.velocity(in: someView)
    return abs(velocity.y) > abs(velocity.x)
}
```

Comment: tried this, but translation is often == (0,0), so it's not precise

Comment: The (0,0) problem is not apparent when velocityInView: is used instead of translationInView:.

Comment: @cbh2000 I updated the answer to use `velocityInView` instead of `translationInView`.

Comment: @JoeBlow A UISwipeGestureRecognizer is an easy way to fire off a transition in response to a swipe gesture, but it's a discrete gesture. If someone is looking for a continuious approach—as to animate a transition with a gesture—a UIPanGestureRecognizer is the way to go.

Answer (score 89):

I created a solution with subclassing like in the answer @LocoMike provided, but used the more effective detection mechanism via initial velocity as provided by @Hejazi. I'm also using Swift, but this should be easy to translate to Obj-C if desired.

Advantages over other solutions:

- Simpler and more concise than other subclassing solutions. No additional state to manage.
- Direction detection happens prior to sending Began action, so your pan gesture selector receives no messages if the wrong direction is swiped.
- After initial direction is determined, direction logic is no longer consulted. This results in the generally desired behavior of activating your recognizer if the initial direction is correct, but does not cancel the gesture after it has begun if a user's finger doesn't travel perfectly along the direction.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

enum PanDirection {
    case vertical
    case horizontal
}

class PanDirectionGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer {

    let direction: PanDirection

    init(direction: PanDirection, target: AnyObject, action: Selector) {
        self.direction = direction
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

        if state == .began {
            let vel = velocity(in: view)
            switch direction {
            case .horizontal where fabs(vel.y) > fabs(vel.x):
                state = .cancelled
            case .vertical where fabs(vel.x) > fabs(vel.y):
                state = .cancelled
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
let panGestureRecognizer = PanDirectionGestureRecognizer(direction: .horizontal, target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

func handlePanGesture(_ pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let percent = max(pan.translation(in: view).x, 0) / view.frame.width

    switch pan.state {
    case .began:
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely the best answer. It's too bad that Apple hasn't added functionality like this to the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Can you provide a usage example?

Comment: This is lovely! Thanks! Works perfectly when stacking both horizontal and vertical: 

`let horizontalPanRecognizer = PanDirectionGestureRecognizer(direction: .horizontal, target: self, action: #selector(handleHorizontalPanGesture(recognizer:)))
        self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(horizontalPanRecognizer);
        
        let verticalPanRecognizer = PanDirectionGestureRecognizer(direction: .vertical, target: self, action: #selector(handleVerticalPanGesture(recognizer:)))
        self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(verticalPanRecognizer);`

Comment: Oh this is awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I tried to constrain the valid area horizontally with UIPanGestureRecognizer.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
        CGPoint velocity = [panGesture velocityInView:panGesture.view];

        double radian = atan(velocity.y/velocity.x);
        double degree = radian * 180 / M_PI;

        double thresholdAngle = 20.0;
        if (fabs(degree) > thresholdAngle) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Then, only swiping within ***thresholdAngle*** degree horizontally can trigger this pan gesture.

Comment: Great answer. This really helped me out when I was mixing UIScrollView gestures and regular gestures. I think the example meant to say "thresholdAngle" instead of "enableThreshold". And you should rarely ever  use atan() because it can produce a NAN. Use atan2() instead.

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3.0 answer: just handles does the vertical gesture

```
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let pan = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let velocity = pan.velocity(in: self)
        return fabs(velocity.y) > fabs(velocity.x)
    }
    return true

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The following solution solved my problem:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer.view isEqual:self.view] && [otherGestureRecognizer.view isEqual:self.tableView]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This is actually just check if pan is going on main view or tableView.

Comment: Why call -isEqual: to compare if two views are the same? A simple identity check should suffice. gestureRecognizer.view == self.view

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 version of Lee's answer for the lazy

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

enum PanDirection {
    case vertical
    case horizontal
}

class UIPanDirectionGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer {

    let direction : PanDirection

    init(direction: PanDirection, target: AnyObject, action: Selector) {
        self.direction = direction
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

        if state == .began {

            let vel = velocity(in: self.view!)
            switch direction {
            case .horizontal where fabs(vel.y) > fabs(vel.x):
                state = .cancelled
            case .vertical where fabs(vel.x) > fabs(vel.y):
                state = .cancelled
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a custom pan gesture in ***Swift 5***

U can constraint its direction and the max angle in the direction, you can also constraint its minimum speed in the direction.

```
enum PanDirection {
    case vertical
    case horizontal
}

struct Constaint {
    let maxAngle: Double
    let minSpeed: CGFloat

    static let `default` = Constaint(maxAngle: 50, minSpeed: 50)
}


class PanDirectionGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer {

    let direction: PanDirection

    let constraint: Constaint


    init(direction orientation: PanDirection, target: AnyObject, action: Selector, constraint limits: Constaint = Constaint.default) {
        direction = orientation
        constraint = limits
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        let tangent = tan(constraint.maxAngle * Double.pi / 180)
        if state == .began {
            let vel = velocity(in: view)
            switch direction {
            case .horizontal where abs(vel.y)/abs(vel.x) > CGFloat(tangent) || abs(vel.x) < constraint.minSpeed:
                state = .cancelled
            case .vertical where abs(vel.x)/abs(vel.y) > CGFloat(tangent) || abs(vel.y) < constraint.minSpeed:
                state = .cancelled
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

call like this:

```
    let pan = PanDirectionGestureRecognizer(direction: .vertical, target: self, action: #selector(self.push(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

    @objc func push(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        if gesture.state == .began{
            // command for once
        }
    }
```

or

```
    let pan = PanDirectionGestureRecognizer(direction: .horizontal, target: self, action: #selector(self.push(_:)), constraint: Constaint(maxAngle: 5, minSpeed: 80))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I took [Lee Goodrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3969588/lee-goodrich)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30607392) and extended it as I needed specifically a single direction pan.  Use it like this: `let pan = PanDirectionGestureRecognizer(direction: .vertical(.up), target: self, action: #selector(handleCellPan(_:)))`

I also added some commenting to make it a little clearer what decisions are actually being made.

```
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

enum PanVerticalDirection {
    case either
    case up
    case down
}

enum PanHorizontalDirection {
    case either
    case left
    case right
}

enum PanDirection {
    case vertical(PanVerticalDirection)
    case horizontal(PanHorizontalDirection)
}

class PanDirectionGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer {

    let direction: PanDirection

    init(direction: PanDirection, target: AnyObject, action: Selector) {
        self.direction = direction
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

        if state == .began {
            let vel = velocity(in: view)
            switch direction {

            // expecting horizontal but moving vertical, cancel
            case .horizontal(_) where fabs(vel.y) > fabs(vel.x):
                state = .cancelled

            // expecting vertical but moving horizontal, cancel
            case .vertical(_) where fabs(vel.x) > fabs(vel.y):
                state = .cancelled

            // expecting horizontal and moving horizontal
            case .horizontal(let hDirection):
                switch hDirection {

                    // expecting left but moving right, cancel
                    case .left where vel.x > 0: state = .cancelled

                    // expecting right but moving left, cancel
                    case .right where vel.x < 0: state = .cancelled
                    default: break
                }

            // expecting vertical and moving vertical
            case .vertical(let vDirection):
                switch vDirection {
                    // expecting up but moving down, cancel
                    case .up where vel.y > 0: state = .cancelled

                    // expecting down but moving up, cancel
                    case .down where vel.y < 0: state = .cancelled
                    default: break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error in `override func touchesMoved` - `Method does not override any method from its superclass`.

Comment: @Annjawn You have to use "import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass"

Comment: Ok. I wasn’t aware of that. I thought import UIKit would automatically import it. I’ll give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2**

The solution is just for only support pan gesture vertically, same as horizontal.

```
let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(test1))
pan.cancelsTouchesInView = false
panView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
```

**Solution 1**:

```
@objc func panAction(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let velocity = pan.velocity(in: panView)
        guard abs(velocity.y) > abs(velocity.x) else {
            return
        }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
  [UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left, .right].forEach { direction in
        let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeAction))
        swipe.direction = direction
        panView.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
        pan.require(toFail: swipe)
    }
```

Then the swipe gesture will swallow the pan gesture. Of course, you don't need to do anything in `swipeAction`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the direction dragging on `UIView` through `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Please follow the code.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    flipFoward = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doFlipForward:)];
    [flipFoward setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [flipFoward setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [flipFoward setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:flipFoward];
    flipBack = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doFlipBack:)];
    [flipBack setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [flipBack setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [flipBack setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:flipBack];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark RESPONDER

-(void)doFlipForward:(UIGestureRecognizer *)aGestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"doFlipForward");
    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)aGestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
    }
    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)aGestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged");
    }
    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)aGestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
    }
}

-(void)doFlipBack:(UIGestureRecognizer *)aGestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"doFlipBack");
    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)aGestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan1");
    }
    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)aGestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged1");
    }
    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)aGestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded1");
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark DELEGATE

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    CGSize size = [self.view bounds].size;
    CGFloat touchX = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view].x;
    if((gestureRecognizer == flipFoward) 
       && touchX >= (size.width - 88.0f))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    if((gestureRecognizer == flipBack)
       && touchX <= 88.0f)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Actually this is not good solution cos only those 88 points from left are able to pan.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I resolved:

First I enabled Simultaneously PanGesture Recognition.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

return YES;
```

Then I Isolate Horizontal and Vertical Pan gestures (accumulator is NSMutableArray property):

```
- (void)verticalPan :(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) sender {

CGPoint touch  = [sender translationInView:self];
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touch];
[accumulator addObject:value];

int firstXObjectValue = (int)[[accumulator objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue].x ;
int lastXObjectValue =  (int)[[accumulator lastObject] CGPointValue].x;

int firstYObjectValue = (int)[[accumulator objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue].y;
int lastYObjectValue =  (int)[[accumulator lastObject] CGPointValue].y;

if (abs(lastYObjectValue - firstYObjectValue) < 4 && abs(lastXObjectValue - firstXObjectValue) > 4) {
    NSLog(@"Horizontal Pan");

    //do something here
}
else if (abs(lastYObjectValue - firstYObjectValue) > 4 && abs(lastXObjectValue - firstXObjectValue) < 4){
    NSLog(@"Vertical Pan");

    //do something here
}

if (accumulator.count > 3)
    [accumulator removeAllObjects];
```

I pushed an example here:

[add custom pan in scrollview](https://github.com/georgepoenaru/add-custom-pan-in-scrollview)

Answer (score 1):

You may use simple `panGestureRecognizer`. No need to use
`pandirectionregognizer` or stuff. Just use y value of `translationInview`
Below code move drag view only up and down

```
- (void)gesturePan_Handle:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];
        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
        [gesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:gesture.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: This code simply pans the view. No directional lock is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

```
let pangesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dragview:")
yourview.addGestureRecognizer(pangesture)


func dragview(panGestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    let touchlocation = panGestureRecognizer.locationInView(parentview)
    yourview.center.y = touchlocation.y //x for horizontal 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)dragAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
      UILabel *label = (UILabel *)gesture.view;
      CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:label];
     label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x + translation.x,
                             label.center.y + 0);
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:label];}
```

I created PanGestureRecognizer @selector action method for the object that needed only Horizontal scrolling.

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(smileyDragged:)];
    [buttonObject addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift way

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        return isVerticalGesture(panGestureRecognizer)
    }
    return false
}

private func isVerticalGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: superview!)
    if fabs(translation.y) > fabs(translation.x) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all you Swift users out there, this will do the job :)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass


class DirectionPanGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer {

let kDirectionPanThreshold = CGFloat(5)
var drag = true
var moveX = CGFloat(0)
var moveY = CGFloat(0)

override init(target: AnyObject, action: Selector) {
    super.init(target: target, action: action)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
    if state == .Failed {
        return
    }

    let nowPoint = touches.anyObject()?.locationInView(view)
    let prevPoint = touches.anyObject()?.previousLocationInView(view)
    moveX += prevPoint!.x - nowPoint!.x
    moveY += prevPoint!.y - nowPoint!.y
    if !drag {
        if abs(moveX) > kDirectionPanThreshold {
            state = .Failed
        } else {
            drag = true
        }

    }

}

 override func reset() {
    super.reset()
    moveX = 0
    moveY = 0
    drag = false
}




}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30607392) by Lee Goodrich and ported to Swift 3

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

enum PanDirection {
    case vertical
    case horizontal
}

class PanDirectionGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer {

    let direction : PanDirection

    init(direction: PanDirection, target: AnyObject, action: Selector) {
        self.direction = direction
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {

        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

        if state == .began {

            let vel = velocity(in: self.view!)

            switch direction {

            case .horizontal where fabs(vel.y) > fabs(vel.x):
                state = .cancelled

            case .vertical where fabs(vel.x) > fabs(vel.y):
                state = .cancelled

            default:
                break

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would love to share my approach because all other approaches are based on either `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` or subclassing `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

My approach is based on runtime and swizzling. I'm not 100% sure about this approach, but you can test and improve it yourself.

Set the direction of any `UIPanGestureRecognizer` with just one line of code:

```
UITableView().panGestureRecognizer.direction = UIPanGestureRecognizer.Direction.vertical
```

use `pod 'UIPanGestureRecognizerDirection'` or the code:

```
public extension UIPanGestureRecognizer {

    override open class func initialize() {
        super.initialize()
        guard self === UIPanGestureRecognizer.self else { return }
        func replace(_ method: Selector, with anotherMethod: Selector, for clаss: AnyClass) {
            let original = class_getInstanceMethod(clаss, method)
            let swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(clаss, anotherMethod)
            switch class_addMethod(clаss, method, method_getImplementation(swizzled), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzled)) {
            case true:
                class_replaceMethod(clаss, anotherMethod, method_getImplementation(original), method_getTypeEncoding(original))
            case false:
                method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled)
            }
        }
        let selector1 = #selector(UIPanGestureRecognizer.touchesBegan(_:with:))
        let selector2 = #selector(UIPanGestureRecognizer.swizzling_touchesBegan(_:with:))
        replace(selector1, with: selector2, for: self)
        let selector3 = #selector(UIPanGestureRecognizer.touchesMoved(_:with:))
        let selector4 = #selector(UIPanGestureRecognizer.swizzling_touchesMoved(_:with:))
        replace(selector3, with: selector4, for: self)
    }

    @objc private func swizzling_touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        self.swizzling_touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        guard direction != nil else { return }
        touchesBegan = true
    }

    @objc private func swizzling_touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        self.swizzling_touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        guard let direction = direction, touchesBegan == true else { return }
        defer {
            touchesBegan = false
        }
        let forbiddenDirectionsCount = touches
            .flatMap({ ($0.location(in: $0.view) - $0.previousLocation(in: $0.view)).direction })
            .filter({ $0 != direction })
            .count
        if forbiddenDirectionsCount > 0 {
            state = .failed
        }
    }
}

public extension UIPanGestureRecognizer {

    public enum Direction: Int {

        case horizontal = 0
        case vertical
    }

    private struct UIPanGestureRecognizerRuntimeKeys {
        static var directions = "\(#file)+\(#line)"
        static var touchesBegan = "\(#file)+\(#line)"
    }

    public var direction: UIPanGestureRecognizer.Direction? {
        get {
            let object = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIPanGestureRecognizerRuntimeKeys.directions)
            return object as? UIPanGestureRecognizer.Direction
        }
        set {
            let policy = objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIPanGestureRecognizerRuntimeKeys.directions, newValue, policy)
        }
    }

    fileprivate var touchesBegan: Bool {
        get {
            let object = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIPanGestureRecognizerRuntimeKeys.touchesBegan)
            return (object as? Bool) ?? false
        }
        set {
            let policy = objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIPanGestureRecognizerRuntimeKeys.touchesBegan, newValue, policy)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension CGPoint {

    var direction: UIPanGestureRecognizer.Direction? {
        guard self != .zero else { return nil }
        switch fabs(x) > fabs(y) {
        case true:  return .horizontal
        case false: return .vertical
        }
    }

    static func -(lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: lhs.x - rhs.x, y: lhs.y - rhs.y)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this: which worked for me as per the question describes

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### SWIFT 4.2

I went further and make a direction Pan Gesture:

```
enum PanDirection {
    case up
    case left
    case right
    case down
}

class PanDirectionGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer {
    
    fileprivate let direction: PanDirection
    
    init(direction: PanDirection, target: AnyObject, action: Selector) {
        self.direction = direction
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        
        guard state != .failed else { return }

        let vel = velocity(in: view)

        let velocities: [PanDirection: CGFloat]
            = [.up: -vel.y,
               .left: -vel.x,
               .right: vel.x,
               .down: vel.y]

        let sortedKeys = velocities.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }

        if let key = sortedKeys.last?.key,
            key != direction {
            state = .cancelled
        }
    }
}
```

(Used: https://github.com/fastred/SloppySwiper and https://stackoverflow.com/a/30607392/5790492)

Answer (score -1):

`PanGestureRecognizer` interface contains the following definitions:

```
unsigned int    _canPanHorizontally:1;
unsigned int    _canPanVertically:1;
```

I didn't check this, but maybe it's accessible via subclass.

Comment: looks promising, but that API isn't exposed. Use of private APIs generally results in rejection by Apple.