# Pass events from (UITableViewCell->UIScrollView) to owning UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a standard `UITableView` which is populated with custom cells which are displayed using a `UIImageView`. I could tap on the images which would fire the `UITableView's` method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

However I wanted to enable pinch zooming on these images which requires nesting the `UIImageView` in a `UIScrollView`, so that's what I did. It looks like this:

```
@interface SMLargeGalleryCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *assetImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end
```

However, now when I tap on the images, the `UITableView` no longer receives a call to  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. If I tap BETWEEN the cells, the event will fire. The issue seems to be that the `UIScrollView` is not forwarding the events.

How can I make this happen?
I'm thinking something along the lines of this (although I know this is ridiculous):

```
-(IBAction)myScrollViewAction:(id)sender{
   self.scrollView.parentTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath.....;
}
```

What am I missing here?
Is this something that has to do with responder chain?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to the question which seems to be structurally similar to yours: [Horizontal UIScrollView having vertical UIScrollViews inside - how to prevent scrolling of inner scroll views when scrolling outer horizontal view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272860/horizontal-uiscrollview-having-vertical-uiscrollviews-inside-how-to-prevent-sc)

Shortly my solution was to hack on both:

1) **shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer** of **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol**.

Using it you can catch gestures on both your tableview and cell simultaneously.

2) Native UIScrollView's **panGestureRecognizer**.

Since UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView it should have **panGestureRecognizer** (and maybe some others) as well.

Just see the pattern I've used - I believe you may transform it to be used in your case.