# pan gesture of UIImageView interfers the scroll

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, scroll, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to implement the functionality of pan gesture to a imageview, this imageview is a subview of a scroll view. the problem is when i try to scroll the scrollview the pan gesture of the imageview gets recognized, and the scrollview does not scroll.
please help me with this.

this is the code for initializing the pan to the uiimageview:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
            [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
            [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
            [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
            [[[scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:i] addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

the imageview has the user set to "YES"

and the action for it

```
-(void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [[[[[sender view] superview] superview] superview]  bringSubviewToFront:sender.view];


    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        if ([[[sender view] superview] superview] == itemView) // adds the imageview in the item scroll
        {
            int tag = [[sender view] tag] / 100;
            UIScrollView *tempScroll = (UIScrollView *)[itemView viewWithTag:-tag];
            CGRect frame = CGRectFromString([itemFrameDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[sender view] tag]]]);

            CGAffineTransform transform = temp.transform;
            UIImageView *tempImageView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [(UIImageView *) [sender view] image]];
            tempImageView.tag = [[sender view] tag];
            //NSLog(@"[sender view] superview] : %@", [[sender view] superview]);
            tempImageView.frame = frame;
            [tempImageView setTransform:transform];
            [tempImageView setFrame:frame];
            [tempImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [tempScroll addSubview:tempImageView];

            UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
            [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
            [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
            [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
            [tempImageView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
            [singleTapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
            [tempImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
        }
    }

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translatedPoint = [sender locationInView:[[sender view] superview]] ;
        newTranslatedPoint = [[[sender view] superview] convertPoint:translatedPoint toView:self.view];

        if ([sender view].frame.size.width == 35 && [sender view].frame.size.height == 35)
            [[sender view] sizeToFit];

        [sender view].center =  CGPointMake(newTranslatedPoint.x, newTranslatedPoint.y); //startFrame;

        [self.view addSubview:[sender view]];
    }

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint newPoint = [[[sender view] superview] convertPoint:newTranslatedPoint toView:itemView];
        if (newPoint.y < 0)// || !viewUp)
        {
            //NSLog(@" baseView");
            [baseView addSubview:[sender view]];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
            [doubleTapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
            [[sender view] addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGestureRecognizer];

            UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
            [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
            [[sender view] addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

            UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
            [rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
            [[sender view] addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];
        }

        else if (newPoint.y > 0)// && viewUp )
        {
            //NSLog(@" itemView");
            int tag = [[sender view] tag] / 100;
            UIScrollView *tempScroll = (UIScrollView *)[itemView viewWithTag:-tag];
            CGRect frame = CGRectFromString([itemFrameDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[sender view] tag]]]);

            CGAffineTransform transform = temp.transform;
            [[sender view] setTransform:transform];
            [[sender view] setFrame:frame];
            [tempScroll addSubview:[sender view]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what did you do in the implementation of the pan gesture.

Comment: Also while using IB, by default, the `UIImageView` is not user interaction enabled. For gesture recognizers on imageview, you'll have to enable that.

Comment: @zen i have added the code which I am using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve exactly by using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on a `UIImageView` that is already in a `UIScrollView`. But from your description, it sounds like you want the `UIScrollView` to do it's thing and for the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to not block that. I believe you need to implement this delegate method for your `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Please read the [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate Protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:) in regards to allowing simultaneous gesture recognition. According to the documentation:

> The default implementation returns NO—no two gestures can be
>   recognized simultaneously.

/* EDIT */

From [UIPanGestureRecognizer - Only vertical or horizontal:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8603839/159758)
Implement just one direction for a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. This is for a vertical pan:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:someView];
    return fabs(translation.y) > fabs(translation.x);
}
```

Comment: actually i am implementing drag and drop functionality here

Comment: i have already implemented this

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}

Comment: @Khushboo so you're trying to move the UIImageView around within the UIScrollView? Is the UIScrollView only to be scrolled vertically/horizontally, or both?

Comment: @Khushboo have you set the contentSize for the UIScrollView correctly? Does scrolling work the way you want it to work if you don't add the panRecognizer? Could you provide more context of your setup, it looks like you're in a for loop given the reference to i.

Comment: I have a scrollview which scrolls vertically only and have around 20 imageview in it, I have given pan gesture to all these 20 imageviews so that I can drag them to other view, but the problem is when I am scrolling the scrollview, while touching the imageview the pan gesture gets recognised and the imageview gets drag instead of the scrollview scrolling, but when I scroll the scrollview while touching the blank area between the 2 imageviews the scrollview scrolls perfectly

Comment: so you only want the gesture to work horizontally since the scrolling happens vertically?

Comment: I want if the user pans the imageview horizontally than panGesture should work and if horizontally then the scrollview should scroll

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28085/discussion-between-khushboo-and-donnalea)

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100884/uipangesturerecognizer-only-vertical-or-horizontal

Comment: @Khushboo glad to hear it. Which bit in particular did the trick and I can edit my answer more specifically.