# Moving images sliding in a "rail"

Tags: ios, image, slide

I have an image which I would like to move around in a rail.

When I put my finger on it, i will only be able to move it up and down, and not from side to side. And how do I make them "stick" at either the top or the bottom? (or both)

Thanks.

Comment: By not changing the the x-coord when drawing the image in the new location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answer(s) here - [UIPanGestureRecognizer - Only vertical or horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100884/uipangesturerecognizer-only-vertical-or-horizontal)

> > Just do this for the vertical pan gesture recognizer, it works for me:

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
     CGPoint translation = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:someView];
     return fabs(translation.y) > fabs(translation.x); }
```

Comment: So this question is a dupe?

Comment: Similar, I have flagged it

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, but how would you get that sweet sweet rep if you just close voted it?

Comment: I could of slightly tweaked the answer and just pasted code right ;)

Comment: Thanks, obviously I didn't know what to search for...