# Set UIScrollview Scroll Direction

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I set the content size so vertical scrolling becomes activated but I only want the user to be able to scroll north and not south.  Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

```
//set high greater than view
myScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: myView.view.frame.width,height: myView.view.frame.height + 190)
```

I only want the ability to scroll up and disable the ability to scroll down which is the default direction of the scrollview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the content offset of the scroll view to the bottom. i.e.,

`myScroll.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 190)` // Here 190 is the same value that represent the height increase done in contentSize.

Comment: and if you want to scroll Left rather than Right (if your scrolling is only horizental)

myScroll.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: yourScrollWidth,y: 0)

Answer (score 1):

Make a subclass of `UIScrollView`. Override `layoutSubviews` to make sure `contentOffset.y` only increases, except when it's beyond the end of the content range, so the scroll view can bounce at the bottom.

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {
    var priorOffset = CGPoint.zero

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        var offset = contentOffset

        if offset.y < priorOffset.y {
            let yMax = contentSize.height - bounds.height
            if offset.y < yMax {
                offset.y = priorOffset.y
                contentOffset = offset
            }
        }
        priorOffset = offset

        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: one-way scroll view]

Answer (score 0):

1. select your Scrollview
2. select identity inspector
3. set user define attributes (see image)

   in image first 435 vertical scrolling & second 116 is horizontal scroll

**Note :** set your own scrolling

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the direction of `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which is attached to your `UIScrollView`.

Check out some popular question which has an up-to-date answer, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100884/uipangesturerecognizer-only-vertical-or-horizontal).

Or just go with `pod 'UIPanGestureRecognizerDirection'`