# How to track onReachBottom event in PDFKit

Tags: swift, pdfkit

I want to unlock Button, when user scroll to the end of document.
I create PDFView like:

```
import PDFKit
import SwiftUI

struct PDFDocumentView: UIViewRepresentable {

    private var url: URL?
    private let pdfDocumentDelegate: PdfDocumentDelegate = PdfDocumentDelegate()

    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        if let url {
            pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
            pdfView.autoScales = true
            pdfView.setNeedsLayout()
            pdfView.layoutIfNeeded()
            pdfView.maxScaleFactor = 3.0
            pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
        }
        return pdfView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `PDFView` doesn't have a public API to do this.

If you have control over the PDF file you show, you can add a very small (in terms of page height) page at the end of the document, observe the [`PDFViewVisiblePagesChanged`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1503651-pdfviewvisiblepageschanged) notification, and check `pdfView.visiblePages` contains the last page of `pdfView.document`.

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .PDFViewVisiblePagesChanged, object: pdfView)
    .sink { notification in
        if let pdfView = notification.object as? PDFView,
           let doc = pdfView.document,
           let lastPage = doc.page(at: doc.pageCount - 1),
           pdfView.visiblePages.contains(lastPage)  {
            print("Reached bottom!")
        }
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Otherwise, you can try to find a `UIScrollView` in the view hierarchy of the `PDFView`, though this is not documented.

With this scroll view, you can either implement its delegate methods, `scrollViewDidScroll` or `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` depending on your preference (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60294428/5133585)), or use KVO to observe changes to `contentOffset` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70266667/5133585)).

After you are able to detect scrolling, you can check if the scroll view is at the bottom by checking `contentOffset` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745900/5133585)).

Here is an example:

```
var pdfView: PDFView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    pdfView = PDFView(...)
    // configure pdfView however you want...
    pdfView.document = ...
    // on iOS 17 at least, subviews[0] is the scroll view
    // to be more future proof, consider searching recursively
    scrollViewDelegate = (pdfView.subviews[0] as? UIScrollView)?.delegate
    (pdfView.subviews[0] as? UIScrollView)?.delegate = self
}

var scrollViewDelegate: UIScrollViewDelegate?

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollViewDelegate?.scrollViewDidEndDecelerating?(scrollView)
    if scrollView.isAtBottom {
        print("Reached bottom!")
    }
}

// you should implement all the other UIScrollViewDelegate methods like this,
// in case PDFView needs them
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollViewDelegate?.scrollViewDidScroll?(scrollView)
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollViewDelegate?.scrollViewDidZoom?(scrollView)
}
```

`UIScrollView.isAtBottom` is from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745900/5133585):

```
extension UIScrollView {
    var isAtBottom: Bool {
        return contentOffset.y >= verticalOffsetForBottom
    }
    
    var verticalOffsetForBottom: CGFloat {
        let scrollViewHeight = bounds.height
        let scrollContentSizeHeight = contentSize.height
        let bottomInset = contentInset.bottom
        let scrollViewBottomOffset = scrollContentSizeHeight + bottomInset - scrollViewHeight
        return scrollViewBottomOffset
    }
}
```